# Best way to use agile for 1 day projects

Tags: agile

I am currently project managing several projects, they are all one day long however I am struggling to set up project planning for them given that the projects are delivered in a single day. In that day, the requirements often do change in an adhoc way. In addition to this, there are multiple one day projects to project manage. I currently use Trello to project manage. If I use one Trello board it could lead to confusion, since the backlog items will be mixed up with different projects. If I create a new Trello board for each client/project, I feel that it will be excessive since the projects are typically one day long.

What is the best way to structure the project planning?

Comment: I've had a bit of experience with this in the form of game jams (game development happening with small teams in 24 - 48 hours and aimed at  prototypes) at an already-agile company. I have a few questions - how close is the client in terms of communication and access? How do changes happen -  review/feedback/input, etc and how are they validated (or not validated)? Do you *require* an online tool, or would physical be OK (and are teams co-located)? Are the projects ever related, i.e. hard dependencies or building on previous discovery?  Any more context you can provide will influence advice. :)

Comment: Specifically on the Trello functionality part of this - the way I manage multiple categories on the one Trello board is to use a classification prefix in the card name. Eg for the "Intranet project" I prefix the cards with [INTRA], for BAU work I prefix the cards with [BAU]. Then you can quickly search/filter for a specific prefix and the board shows only the cards that relate to that project. As for the rest of it, I agree with @JeffLindsey that some more context/info would be great in order to give the best advice!

Answer (score 2):

If you have your heart set on using Trello, I'd recommend either using a separate board per project, or using [Labels](http://help.trello.com/article/797-adding-labels-to-cards) so you can quickly filter the board on a project-by-project basis. I've created an example board that demonstrates this [here](https://trello.com/b/EGmDMrQs).

If your team are co-located, have you considered devoting a wall/whiteboard to a Kanban board? You could then use swim lanes to separate projects from one another.

But remember, Agile is a *mindset*, not a planning technique.

Comment: +1. It also sounds like you're trying to figure out how to manage your flow of work - if you haven't already, I'd look into what Kanban has to offer. Note that Agile and Kanban are not at all mutually exclusive, but I feel like this is really more about flow of work than agility.

Answer (score 1):

If you have really one day-long projects, handle each project as a work item (or a card), and move it on your board phase to phase (phase: todo, development, testing, deploy etc.). With this approach you can see if they are really one day long, and see how many projects you have in a phase.

Comment: "Many 1 day projects" sounds like one long project to me too

Comment: If the are related or dependent on each other then yes.

Comment: would using the same resource pool relate them in your mind?

Comment: nope. When I see projects I consider them related if they depend functionality wise. A team can work on a signup and a facelift features. The team is the same, but the functionalities are not. However if the team works on signup but needs paypal integration, that is a dependency. In this case two teams can be involved as well.